# Change QStackedLayout Index with QPushButton not QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I do this in Qt Creator. I want to change my QStackedLayout with only QPushButton, not QComboBox. Is this possible? Anybody has implemented this? I got many example from Qt Documentation but all examples use QComboBox (now QPushButton like I need). This is my code:

```
#mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

Dialog::Dialog()
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainlayout     =   new QVBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *layouta        =   new QVBoxLayout;
    QVBoxLayout *layoutb        =   new QVBoxLayout;
    QPushButton *tombola        =   new QPushButton("A");
    QPushButton *tombolb        =   new QPushButton("B");
    QPushButton *tombolc        =   new QPushButton("C");
    QFrame      *framea         =   new QFrame;
    QFrame      *frameb         =   new QFrame;
    QStackedLayout *stackia     =   new QStackedLayout;

    layouta->addWidget(tombola);
    layoutb->addWidget(tombolb);

    framea->setLayout(layouta);
    frameb->setLayout(layoutb);
    framea->setMinimumSize(88,88);
    frameb->setMinimumSize(88,88);

    //building frame
    framea->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    framea->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
    frameb->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    frameb->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);

    //get c button smaller
    tombolc->setMaximumWidth(33);

    stackia->addWidget(framea);
    stackia->addWidget(frameb);
    stackia->addWidget(tombolc);

    mainlayout->addLayout(stackia);
    QPushButton     *tombold    =   new QPushButton("D");
    mainlayout->addWidget(tombold);
    setLayout(mainlayout);

    connect(tombold, SIGNAL(clicked()), stackia, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(1))); //CONNECTOR
}
```

**RESULT**

Qt Creator says:

> Object::connect: No such slot QStackedLayout::setCurrentIndex(1)

What is my mistake?

At second chance after searching and asking for 4 days, I have changed my connect() and function code into:

**CONNECTOR**:

```
connect(tombold, SIGNAL(clicked()), stackia, SLOT(change_stack()));
```

**FUNCTION**:
    void Dialog::change_stack()
    {
        stackia->setCurrentIndex(1);
    }

**RESULT**

But Qt Creator says:

> Object::connect: No such slot QStackedLayout::change_stack()

and immediately the window closed.

At my sight, my code has error. But I don't know what error so I can't change QStackLayout content/page into another page. What is my mistake? I believe this is actually quite simple but I just don't know where is the error.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `change_stack` function to your `Dialog` class and connect to it like this:

```
class Dialog : public QWidget
{
    ...
    private slots:
    void change_stack();

private:
    QStackedLayout *stackia;
}

Dialog::Dialog
{
    ...
    connect(tombold, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(change_stack()));
    ...
}


void Dialog::change_stack()
{
    stackia->setCurrentIndex(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But my mainwindow.cpp is still same http://tempel.blankon.in/146191. I have implemented your suggestion on my mainwindow.h so I changed it into this: http://tempel.blankon.in/146192. But indeed Qt Creator says:  

 error: multiple definition of `Dialog::change_stack()'   <br/>

 first defined here   <br/>

 In function `Dialog::change_stack()':   <br/>

 error: multiple definition of `Dialog::change_stack()'   <br/>

What is my mistake on the codes?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning

```
connect(tombold, SIGNAL(clicked()), stackia, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(1)));
```

A slot can only have as many parameters or less parameters than a signal.
E.g. you can do

```
connect( sender  , SIGNAL( somethingHappened( const QString& ) ),
         receiver, SLOT  ( doSomething      ( const QString& ) ) );
```

and you can do

```
// connect signal and ignore the parameter
connect( sender  , SIGNAL( somethingHappened( const QString& ) ),
         receiver, SLOT  ( doSomethingElse  (                ) ) );
```

but you cannot do

```
// this will not work
connect( sender  , SIGNAL( somethingElseHappened(                ) ),
         receiver, SLOT  ( doSomething          ( const QString& ) ) );
```

What you probably want is something like this:

```
Dialog::Dialog
{
    ...
    // This must be a member variable
    _stackia = new QStackedLayout();

    tombola->setProperty( "tabpage", 1 );
    tombolb->setProperty( "tabpage", 2 );
    tombolc->setProperty( "tabpage", 3 );

    connect( tombola, SIGNAL( clicked       () ),
             this   , SLOT  ( tombol_clicked() ) );
    connect( tombolb, SIGNAL( clicked       () ),
             this   , SLOT  ( tombol_clicked() ) );
    connect( tombolc, SIGNAL( clicked       () ),
             this   , SLOT  ( tombol_clicked() ) );
}

// This must be defined as slot in the header
void Dialog::tombol_clicked()
{
    int index = sender()->property( "tabpage" ).toInt();
    _stackia->setCurrentIndex( index );
}
```